# Remove all elements with specific class from text

Tags: jquery, html

How to remove all DOM elements with specific class from text?

```
var html = "<table>"+
"<tr>"+
"<td>1</td>"+
"<td>2</td>"+
"<td class='del'>3</td>"+
"</tr>"+
"<tr>"+
"<td>1</td>"+
"<td>2</td>"+
"<td class='del'>3</td>"+
"</tr>"+
"</table>";
```

Comment: [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: You want to remove them from the `html` variable, instead of removing them from the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert HTML to DOM objects, remove specified items, and get its HTML back:

```js
var html = "<table>" +
    "<tr>" +
    "<td>1</td>" +
    "<td>2</td>" +
    "<td class='del'>3</td>" +
    "</tr>" +
    "<tr>" +
    "<td>1</td>" +
    "<td>2</td>" +
    "<td class='del'>3</td>" +
    "</tr>" +
    "</table>";

var $obj = $(html); // Create jQuery object
$obj.find(".del").remove(); // Remove .del items
var htmlNew = $obj[0].outerHTML; // Get the updated HTML
 
// Demonstration purposes only:
$("body").text(htmlNew);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Remember that `.html()` is going to return only inner html which won't include `<table>` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to first parse the html string as DOM, then remove specific children using classname

```
var htmlString = "html string"
var parser = new DOMParser()
var doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/xml");

$(doc).find('className').remove()//remove specific elements

var filteredHtml=$(doc).html()//get the new html string after removing the elements
```